# What is the best way to check if a string can be parsed into an int array?

Tags: c#

I need to determine if a string can be parsed into an array of int. The string MAY be in the format

> "124,456,789,0"

In case which can it can converted thus:

```
int[] Ids = SearchTerm.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

However the string may also be something like:

> "Here is a string, it is very nice."

In which case the parsing fails.

The logic currently branches in two directions based on whether the string contains a comma character (assuming that only the array-like strings will contain this character) but this logic is now flawed and comma characters are now appearing in other strings.

I could put a Try..Catch around it but I am generally adverse to controlling logic flow by exceptions.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Compare the speed of an exception vs a regex precondition. Choose the faster one.

Comment: @leppie: Who said that speed is more important than code clarity, robustness, maintainability, etc?

Comment: @leppie: Also, what speed are you talking about? When I debug a piece of code that is failing I turn on "break on every exception" because every exception, even a handled exception, could be a hidden bug. Any code that produces a lot of noisy exceptions slows down my ability to debug the entire codebase, and that is VERY VERY EXPENSIVE. My time is not cheap! That's the scarce resource that you should be optimizing for: time that is money.

Comment: @EricLippert: a try/catch surely has more clarity than a regex ;p But I agree with the stance on exceptions, I normally debug with break on all exceptions too (I avoid them like the plague). It is my biggest gripe with the crap 'enterprise' Java developers 'produce'.

Comment: @ericlippert, to bad the dot net library teams did not agree with you. I hate all the hidden exceptions you get when debugging applications with XmlSerializer (filenotfound), WCF (keynotfound) and Task (operationcanceled).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I could put a Try..Catch around it but I am generally adverse to controlling logic flow by exceptions

Good attitude. If you can avoid the exception, do so.

A number of answers have suggested

```
int myint;
bool parseFailed = SearchTerm.Split(',')
                             .Any( s => !int.TryParse(s, out myint));
```

Which is not bad, but not great either. I would be inclined to first, write a better helper method:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static int? TryParseAsInteger(this string s)
    {
        int j;
        bool success = int.TryParse(s, out j);
        if (success)
            return j;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Now you can say:

```
bool parseFailed = SearchTerm.Split(',')
                             .Any( s => s.TryParseAsInteger() == null);
```

But I assume that what you really want is *the parsed state* if it can succeed, rather than just answering the question "would a parse succeed?" With this helper method you can say:

```
List<int?> parse = SearchTerm.Split(',')
                             .Select( s => s.TryParseAsInteger() )
                             .ToList();
```

And now if the list contains any nulls, you know that it was bad; if it doesn't contain any nulls then you have the results you wanted:

```
int[] results = parse.Contains(null) ? null : parse.Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1, (Hypothetically) would it be good if the Framework implemented `t? t.TryParse(string s)` methods?

Comment: @Jodrell: Yes, that would be very helpful; I wish the BCL team would have done so back in .NET 2.0 when nullables were added. Fortunately as you can see they are very easy to write yourself.

Comment: although its (currently) hard to write a static extension. You may tell us its hard to extend the compiler to support static extensions.

Answer (score 5):

```
int myint;
bool parseFailed = SearchTerm.Split(',')
                           .Any( s => !int.TryParse(s, out myint));
```

Comment: logically I prefer `AndAlso All` as oppossed to `OrElse Not Any` but my point is moot.

Comment: @Jodrell: But that will have to test every token

Comment: @leppie, unless I'm mistake "The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined." which will be after the first false or at the end. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @leppie in much the same was a `Any` stops after the first true.

Comment: @Jodrell: True, must be bed-time for me :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiline lambda expression to get `int.TryParse` for every `Split` method result:

```
var input = "124,456,789,0";

var parts = input.Split(new [] {","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var numbers
    = parts.Select(x =>
                    {
                        int v;
                        if (!int.TryParse(x, out v))
                            return (int?)null;
                        return (int?)v;
                    }).ToList();

if (numbers.Any(x => !x.HasValue))
    Console.WriteLine("string cannot be parsed as int[]");
else
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
```

It will not only check if value can be parsed to `int`, but also return the value if it can, so you don't have to do the parsing twice.

Comment: but, is it worth carrying on if parsing fails?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you first remove the characters from the string and use

```
bool res = int.TryParse(text1, out num1);
```

Example below has no limit. 
The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds.
[BigInteger MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    string test = "20,100,100,100,100,100,100";
    test = test.Replace(",", "");
    BigInteger num1 = 0;
    bool res = BigInteger.TryParse(test, out num1);
```

Comment: I think what Marko means is "Remove all the commas, then check if the remaining characters form a number that can be parsed."

Comment: Integer overflow exception.

Comment: @gunr2171, yes that's what i meant. Remove all non digit characters and try to parse the string as an int. If you have a integer overflow use int64.

Comment: @Marko even if you use UInt64 you'll have a very small range: 20,100,100,100,100,100,100 will overflow. IMO It's pretty fragile.

Comment: @Adriano I am not sure what the range of the string is but i have modified my example to handle your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
int dummy;
var parsable = SearchTerm.Split(',').All(s => int.TryParse(s, out dummy));
```

<s>but if you are doing that you might as well just catch the exception</s>

Comment: This is a worst practice. **Never catch an avoidable exception. Rather, avoid the exception.**  This is the polite thing to do; remember, someone debugging the program is going to see *every exception* whether it is handled or not, because even a handled exception might be a bug! Don't go making work for yourself in the future; a program should be very "quiet" in exceptions whenever possible. **Exceptions should be exceptional**. If there is a code path on which you expect to get an avoidable exception then something is wrong with your design.

Comment: @EricLippert I can't argue with that. Now you've got me thinking, despite thier utility, is there something inherently wrong with the .Net frameworks `TryParse` implementations?

Comment: Yes there is, but it is not their fault. `TryParse` methods are good because they allow you to avoid an avoidable exception. `Parse` does not; if it throws when the string is not an integer then you cannot avoid the exception unless you parse the string, at which point you don't need to call `Parse`! The flaw in `TryParse` is that it requires a *variable* to mutate; the better technique is shown in my answer. `TryParse` should return a nullable, not a bool. But `TryParse` was invented before nullable integers, so that's unavoidable due to causality.

Answer (score 0):

you can use RegEx  to determine if the string match your pattern

something like this

```
       string st = "124,456,789,0";
        string pattS = @"[0-9](?:\d{0,2})";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattS);
        var res = regex.Matches(st);
        foreach (var re in res)
        {
          //your code here   
        }
```

tested  on rubular.com  [here](http://rubular.com/r/bL1weDztlw)

Comment: Based on the OP's wording, I think a string like, "Here are 2 sentences.  They are very nice." should fail entirely.  Your code will happily pull the 2 out and ignore the rest.  Further, your code doesn't handle 4 digit numbers.